# ListView not binding properly using

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I've been plowing through others' questions and responses on this topic all day, but nothing seems to be working. I'm trying to bind an empty ObservableCollection to a ListView that will be filled in as the user adds data. From what I can tell in the output window, the DataContext is not showing the public variable I created to bind to the ListView. I'm still fairly new to WPF so it's likely I missed something, but I just don't see it.

XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fieldAnalysis}" 
      Name="listviewFieldAnalysis">                                          
<ListView.View>
....
```

CS:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<FieldSample> fieldAnalysis;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fieldAnalysis = new ObservableCollection<FieldSample>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
...
```

Output Window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'fieldAnalysis' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=fieldAnalysis; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'ListView' (Name='listviewFieldAnalysis'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

I've read the breakdown of the error message, but I'm still unsure of why the XAML is unable to access the 'fieldAnalysis' variable. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a property and bind to the property.

E.g. in your viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<FieldSample> FieldAnalysis {
   get {
      return fieldAnalysis;
   }
}
```

then in your view:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding FieldAnalysis}"
```

Comment: That was it. I didn't realize that to be accessible to the XAML that explicit getters were needed. Ugh, I'm annoyed with myself by how much time I sunk into this problem to be something so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be like this:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
   private ObservableCollection<FieldSample>_fieldAnalysis;
   public ObservableCollection<FieldSample> fieldAnalysis
   {
    get{return _fieldAnalysis;}
    set{
        _fieldAnalysis=value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
             PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("fieldAnalysis"));
            }
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler  PropertyChanged;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    fieldAnalysis = new ObservableCollection<FieldSample>();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

If you don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Window, you have to instantiate the Observable collection before calling InitializeComponent

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public ObservableCollection<FieldSample> fieldAnalysis;
public MainWindow()
{
    fieldAnalysis = new ObservableCollection<FieldSample>();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about adding a '' to the

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fieldAnalysis}" 

 ItemsSource="{Binding Path='fieldAnalysis'}"
```

not sure about it but i think it will help